# How to automate the export from Active/License Users from Power BI (Microsoft 365) Admin Portal

Tags: powerbi, office365, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, microsoft365

I would like to know if there is any solution how to automate the export of files from Admin Portal / Microsoft defender for Cloud apps instead of manually logging there and doing it by export button. In my case I need active users/licenses that are within company so I can always have it "up-to-date", and moreover the Activity log from Microsoft Defender for Cloud apps.

[image]

[image]

On this page is "Export" button that generate .csv file, but every time I have to do it manually....

And lastly activity log from Cloud apps:

[image]

So, is there any way to make it automatically, with Power automate, Powershell, any kind of "coding" or querying....I am not familiar with this?

I am using Power BI Premium (with admin rights but only for Power BI Administration) and Office 365 ofc.